# Python - Making a program to read a text file of usernames and passwords for authentication

Tags: python-3.x

I have a .txt in which stores the username and password.
**Jane:1234**

I have gotten to the point of reading from the file and storing them.
I then need to get the users input to enter a username and password and authenticate if it is correct.

Comment: Where are you getting user input from?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use .replace and .split

```
account_info = "username:password"
account_info_array = account_info.replace(":", " ").split()
```

['username', 'password']

Comment: I am not sure if that's what the OP is asking for, but if it's that, it can be done without using replace, simply `account_info_array = account_info.split(':')` . But the two methods will fail if the username or the password contains ":"